# One Websocket per tab in Angular

Tags: angular, websocket, tabs

I'm trying to implement a websocket service in angular 4 plus asp.net core on the server side. I just took the WebApp(Angular) template coming with VS2017.

My Server can handle multiple Websockets using a simple WebSocketManager.

On the client side I got a service which provides a method createNewWebSocket something like this:

```
    createNewSocket() : WebSocket {
     let socket = new WebSocket(url);
     return socket;
    }
```

One of my components uses this service like this:

```
     constructor(private websocketService: WebsocketService) {
     }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.socket = this.websocketService.createNewSocket();

       this.socket.onopen = (evt) => {
         console.log('Opened');
       }

       ...

       this.socket.onmessage = (msg) => {
         console.log(msg.data);
       }
     }
```

Everything works fine and I got my random data from Server. Nothing special so far.

But If I try to open the same component(page) in a new tab or in a new browser, I got an error in my service: "WebSocket is not defined". The old one still works.
BUT if I open in a new tab another page(where no websocket service is called)  and then click the link to my "websocket page", everything works fine and all pages receives random and different data!

Why is here a difference?

I hope I've somehow clarified the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, it seems to be a problem with server side prerendering. 
I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47562531/vs-2017-net-core-2-0-angular-4-error-system-net-http-winhttpexception-the-c/47576937#47576937) and the error is gone and I got the desired behavior.

i.e. I changed in the index.cshtml:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to this:

```
<app asp-ng4-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```